# Achieve a transitive association for a query in SailsJS

Tags: database, join, sails.js, associations

My question might be an obvious one, however i've been struggling with this one for a couple of nights. Here's a basic overview of my problem.

I have the following three models:

#### Model 1

```js
/* api/models/Parent.js */

module.exports = {
  tableName: "table1",
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
    },
    children: {
      collection: "child",
      via: "parentId"
    },
  },
};
```

#### Model 2

```js
/* api/models/Child.js */

module.exports = {
  tableName: "table2",
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
    },
    parentId: {
      model: "parent"
    },
    vaccinations: {
      collection: "vaccination",
      via: "childId"
    },
  },
};
```

#### Model 3

```js
/* api/models/Result.js */

module.exports = {
  tableName: "table3",
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
    },
    childId: {
      model: "child"
    },
    vaccinationId: {
      model: "vaccination"
    },
  },
};
```

I wish to be able to query the following
`GET /vaccination?parentId=1` which will retrieve all vaccinations for children that have `parentId=1`. I am not sure what's the best practice to follow here, i would really appreciate any help. I have read the [Through Associations](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations) but for some reason, i can not get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following query might help you here:

```
let children = await Child.find({
  parentId: 1
})
.populate('parentId')
.populate('vaccinations');
```